# Dependency Injection and new objects creation

Tags: oop, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, cdi, ioc-container

I'm new to dependency injection. It seems I have a good understanding of it, but  I am getting a little bit confused about one thing. Suppose I have a bean:

```
@Bean
HttpClient {
  public void void POST(String url, Object payload) {
    .......
  }
}
```

And have a class using that bean:

```
Message {

 public void send() {
  httpClient.POST(this);
 }
}
```

Obviously I should just inject the **HttpCLient** into the **Message**.But....
The **Message** also has a constructor with params:

```
Message {

 private final String text;

 public Message(String text) {
   this.text = text;
 }

 public void send() {
  httpClient.POST(this);
 }
}
```

And it will be used in such way:

```
SomeClient {

  if(....) {
    new Message("Case 1 text").send();
  } else {
      new Message("Case 2 text").send();
   }
}
```

Thus the **Message** is an immutable object that is used per request with new constructor's params and in the same time it needs the heavyweight **HttpClient** to be inject.

Maybe this example is not quite correct, but I believe there is many similar issues you had come across.

So the question is: what should I do if I have to instantiate objects by hands but they require dependencies to be inject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propagating dependencies is usually solved with *Factories*. You don't directly instantiate the `Message`, you use a `Factory` to do it, like this:

```java
messageFactory.createMessage("Text").send();
```

With the message factory being:

```java
public interface MessageFactory {
    Message createMessage(String text);
}
```

And then the dependency to the HTTP Client is in the actual factory:

```java
public final class HttpClientBasedMessageFactory {
    private final HttpClient httpClient;
    ...
    @Override
    public Message createMessage(String text) {
        return new Message(httpClient, text);
    }
}
```

That is now without any dependency injection "framework", but it can be adjusted to support whatever you are using.